# convert string to date object (no timestamp included in csv entry)

Tags: python, csv, datetime, datetime-format

I keep getting a value error here. What am I doing wrong? The CSV I am reading and writing does not have a timestamp with each date entry. The dates are just entered in 'mm-dd-yyyy' format.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Matthew Olive/PycharmProjects/excel_scripts/contango_cleaner.py", line 17, in <module>
    dateS = datetime.strptime(row[2], "%m-%d-%Y")
  File "C:\Users\Matthew Olive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\Matthew Olive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'
```

here is my code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

path = "C:\\Users\\Matthew Olive\\Desktop\\Trading Stuff\\sample_for_python .csv"
file = open(path, newline = '')
reader = csv.reader(file)
data =[]
for row in reader:
    dateC = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%m-%d-%Y")
    dateS = datetime.strptime(row[2], "%m-%d-%Y")
    contango = float(row[1])
    open_price = float(row[3])
    close_price = float(row[4])
    data.append([dateC, contango, dateS, open_price, close_price])
print(data[0])
```

The problem seems to come when I am trying to convert the date strings into proper datetime objects. The end goal of the program is to say "If dateC does not match dateS, then delete the first and second entry in that particular row. Then create a new CSV file and export it into Excel. I am trying to automate a process I do manually a lot. (For each row, the first two columns are not needed if they don't have matching date and float values in the third, fourth, and fifth columns)

Here is how my CSV is structured (columns):
dateC and dateS should be datetime objects while the others are floats

[dateC, contango, dateS, open_price, close_price]

Comment: can you provide `sample_for_python .csv`

Comment: The error message is saying that either `row[0]` or `row[2]` (dependent on which is line 17) is an empty string

Comment: The issue is that one of the rows is missing a date entry. That's why you're running into this problem

Comment: You might want to have a look at `pandas` read_csv() and to_datetime(). `pandas` also offers convenient export of its DataFrames to Excel format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An illustration of my comment; how this could work out using `pandas`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# some example input with missing dates (empty fields in the csv)...
data = io.StringIO("""dateC,contango,dateS,open_price,close_price
02-03-2020,1,02-04-2020,50,55
,2,02-04-2020,51,56
02-03-2020,3,,52,57""")

# just replace 'data' with the path to your csv:
df = pd.read_csv(data)

df['dateC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateC'], errors='coerce')
df['dateS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateS'], errors='coerce')

# df
#        dateC  contango      dateS  open_price  close_price
# 0 2020-02-03         1 2020-02-04          50           55
# 1        NaT         2 2020-02-04          51           56
# 2 2020-02-03         3        NaT          52           57
```

Some references:

- [pandas
  DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
- [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)